# Paypal Express review page buttons not working

Tags: paypal, magento-1.9, express-checkout

I have a serious issue in Paypal when I done the payment through paypal express chekout it redirect back to Mangeto on paypal/express/review page , it do not allow me to place order, the Place order button is showing disable and no action clicking on "update order data" button .

I followed the below link but I haven't got any result.

[Click](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18820/paypal-express-review-page-buttons-not-working)

Please help me,I tried from the last two days.I am ready to share admin detail if required.

Please don't suggest clear cache or enable from admin section I have done all this suggestion.

Comment: Is anyone is here to answer my question...?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to download a fresh copy of magento and copy the files Review.php, review.phmtl and review.js to my site and it worked. I never edited those files maybe the extensions I installed changed those. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

After spending lots of time I got the solution for this problem.

I compressed js and css file for fast execution of my website thats why its happen after remove compression from js file, Paypal start working.